# How to save the Visual GC GUI output

Tags: jvm

I'am using VisualVM to analyze JVM heap memory and as a part of that I'm also using a plugin name as visualGC which represents/shows the different memory components usage of JVM like eden space, Survivor space, Old generation and Metaspace [earlier known as permanent space].
I've run this tool and captured the output of visualGC however would like to store it in some kind of file format so that can refer it at later stage, any idea how to save it? Below is a related screenshot:

[VisualGC-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBvcK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the dump log (dump button) through visualvm, or print the dump log through jmap -heap PID ,jmap -dump, format=b file= dump Hprof PID, the specific commands can be viewed through jmap -help. The dump log printed out can be analyzed by mat (memory analysis tools). Finally, you can analyze it together by setting VM option print GCLog!